# Actionscript 3 - DataGridColumn and having a specific column automatically sorted

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using the DataGrid component in Flash, that is loaded with data via a external XML file. I have a column, A (Serial), which once loaded, I'd like for the information to be sorted Ascendingly, automatically. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import fl.controls.DataGrid;
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
import fl.controls.ScrollPolicy;
import fl.events.DataGridEvent;

var dp:DataProvider;
var A:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Serial");
A.headerText = "Serial No.";
A.width = 100;
A.resizable = false;

var B:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Mold");
B.headerText = "Mold No.";
B.width = 150;
B.resizable = false;

var C:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Type");
C.headerText = "Grid Type: ";
C.width = 350;
C.resizable = false;

var myDataGrid:DataGrid = new DataGrid();

myDataGrid.addColumn(A);
myDataGrid.addColumn(B);
myDataGrid.addColumn(C);

myDataGrid.verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON;
myDataGrid.setSize(600, 800);
myDataGrid.move(0, 0);
myDataGrid.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, headerReleaseHandler);
addChild(myDataGrid);

var url:String = "xml/TEST.xml";
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var uLdr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
uLdr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
uLdr.load(req);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var ldr:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
    var xmlDP:XML = new XML(ldr.data);
    dp = new DataProvider(xmlDP);
    myDataGrid.dataProvider = dp;
}

function headerReleaseHandler(event:DataGridEvent):void {
    var dg:DataGrid = event.currentTarget as DataGrid;
    trace("column: " + String(event.dataField));
    trace("descending: " + String(dg.sortDescending));
}
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try the sortItemsOn() method on the DataGrid.

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#sortItemsOn() for an example how to use it.